# Is there a Wizard skill that makes us go closer to the enemies?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I am a melee wizard and I want to get close and attack enemy in one click. Is there an ability that can help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing to what you're looking for is the [Teleport](http://d3db.com/skill/i/teleport) ability with the [Calamity](http://d3db.com/runestone/i/teleport/a) Rune, unlocked at level 59:

> Casts a low power Wave of Force upon arrival [of your teleport], dealing **75%** weapon damage as Physical to all nearby enemies.

And in general, Teleport will let you get close to anything pretty quickly.

Comment: Calamity runes do 280% damage now.